# Trying to test the bounded nature of the function

Tags: calculus, functions

How the following function is bounded:

$f(x,y)=\frac{2xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

My teacher wrote the above expression and told us that the expression is bounded. But if we see, then

$\frac{2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\leq 2$

Now, function can be written as:

$\frac{2|x|y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\leq 2 |x|$

Clearly, $|x|$ is not bounded. So, the function should not be bounded. Is something wrong with my approach?.

Comment: bounded **where**?

Comment: The function is not bounded on the line $x=y \to 0$ for example. I guess there is some context missing. Your argument is twice flawed anyway, since $\frac{2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\leq 2$ doesn't hold in general and, even if it did, something being lower than an *un*bounded function doesn't mean that the something itself is unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the intended meaning is *a bounded function over $x^2+y^2\geq 1$*, or over $x^2+y^2\geq\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon> 0$. Indeed, by the AM-GM inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz,

$$\left|xy^2\right|=\text{GM}(|x|,|y|,|y|)^3 \leq \left(\frac{|x|+2|y|}{3}\right)^3= \frac{1}{27}(x+2|y|)^3\leq \frac{1}{27}\left(\sqrt{5}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^3 $$
hence
$$ \left|\frac{2xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\leq \frac{10\sqrt{5}}{27}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$